# SQLpp11 installation with PostgreSQL connector

Tags: c++, linux, postgresql, c++11

How do I install SQLpp11 with PostgreSQL connector on Linux?

I use Linux Mint 17.2, Eclipse CDT and I have PostgreSQL 9.4 already installed.

I know, it's trivial but I'm doing this first time. I'm a newbie.

GitHub repository:

- https://github.com/rbock/sqlpp11
- https://github.com/matthijs/sqlpp11-connector-postgresql

Comment: Actually, your English was pretty good! I cleaned it up a little. I hope you find your answer. I'm not 100% sure, but it may be recommended that you ask on a different part of the Stack Exchange network, so just a heads up.

Comment: @JasonMc92 Thanks. "different part of the Stack Exchange network" - what site do you more precisely meant?

Comment: Possibly [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/), or [Super User](http://superuser.com/). However, **do not cross post**. If you believe this'll better fit on one of those, delete this post and go post it on the one site you think it would best go on. Otherwise, wait for someone else to close this and suggest a better fit. I don't have enough experience with this topic to say one way or another. :)

Comment: @JasonMc92 Ok, I will wait for some answers or hints. I think this place is as well as those, because it's (maybe) standard installation of library.

Answer (score 1):

Both repositories are using cmake, therefore you should be fine with

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. # maybe some other options
make
make install
```

in each of the repos, starting with sqlpp11.

Comment: Thanks but now I have installed pqxx 4.0.1 and my program depends on it. So I won't try it out, check if it works and give you ↑. Maybe it will be useful for someone else.